# Merge multiple subforms and submit as a single form in Asp.net MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 1 view model .
And for some user needs and requirements i divided this model into 5 forms here is the example.

```
public class VM_MyModel
{
public string Prop1 {get;set}
public string Prop2 {get;set}
public string Prop3 {get;set}
public string Prop4 {get;set}
public string Prop5 {get;set}
public string Prop6 {get;set}
public string Prop7 {get;set}
public string Prop8 {get;set}
public string Prop9 {get;set}
public string Prop10 {get;set}
}
```

On View there are 5 forms containing model properties accordingly.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("","",FormMethod.Post,new{@id="form1"}))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Prop1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Prop2)
<input type="button" value="Next"/>
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("","",FormMethod.Post,new{@id="form2"}))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Prop3)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Prop4)
<input type="button" value="Next"/>
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("","",FormMethod.Post,new{@id="form3"}))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Prop5)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Prop6)
<input type="button" value="Next"/>
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("","",FormMethod.Post,new{@id="form4"}))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Prop7)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Prop8)
<input type="button" value="Next"/>
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("MyAction","MyController",FormMethod.Post,new{@id="form5"}))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Prop9)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Prop10)
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

Here for all first 4 forms i change the default behaviour and call jquery .valid() function to check weather the form is valid or not if valid then open form2 and so on till the form5 is reached at that form i want to submit my all 5 forms collectively on 1 of my controler action which receive VM_MyModel as parameter. Here the code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(VM_MyModel model)
{
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
model.Save();
RedirectToAction("Home");
}
return View(model);
}
```

Please suggest how to submit this form collectively. Hope you understand my question.
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: you cannot submit more then one form at a time..only one form can be submitted at a time..

Comment: @Kartikeya ok then what is the solution to my problem any alternative.?

Comment: why not just wrap it all in one form?

Comment: yes i agree with @Oliver...just make a single form with one submit button...

Comment: It is dummy example @Oliver actually i have 90 fields within model and use accordion layout design to manage these fields 90 fields are divided into 5 accordion actually.

Comment: @azhar_SE_nextbridge....so what's the problem if you have 5 accordians then take a single form wrapping 90 fields inside accordian...

Comment: Problem is that .valid() is called every time when fields within accordion need to be validate and you know it is possible when these fields are within form

Comment: Even if you have an accordion I see no reason not to wrap the whole accordion in one form and POST all the fields with a single submit.

The next buttons will handle the accordion in javascript so don't need to be inputs but instead can just be an anchor or button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use JavaScript/jQuery and copy all values from the previous forms in hidden inputs in the final form, before submitting it.

First, you should add hidden inputs in your last form like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("MyAction","MyController",FormMethod.Get,new{@id="form5"}))
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="hProp@(i)" id="hProp@(i)" />
        // - or -
        // @Html.Hidden("hProp" + @i)
    }

@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Prop9)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Prop10)
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

Then add this jQuery code to your page:

```
$("input[type='submit']").on("click", function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        $("#hProp" + i).val($("#Prop" + i).val());
    }

});
```

Comment: Right then how to copy all previous forms values into last form.?
ById?

Comment: @SmartDev. I suspect the actual properties are not named `Prop1`, `Prop2` etc. and in any case you per-pended `h` to the name so nothing would bind anyway. The only way to do what your suggesting (_You could_ not _You should_) is to (1) Select all forms except the last then (2) In an `$.each` statement, loop each `input`, `select` and `textarea` and create a new hidden input with the same `name` and `value` attribute of the control. If any of those inputs were `radio` or `checkbox` then additional checks would be needed because the html helpers generate multiple controls with the same name.

Comment: No checkbox and radiobutton on the forms.

Comment: I need to add all form field manually on the 5th form. I am talking about 4 form fields?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well, this was only an example of how this could be done. Depending on the real scenario, you can find another way of generating and fill in all the hidden inputs (you can even add them all manually).

Comment: Or it is accomplish by jquery to save time and effort

Answer (score 0):

You only have one submit button in the last form and it will only submit the controls within that form. I suggest one form, but divide the controls in to sections (I assume you are probably hiding the following sections, so the `Next` buttons would validate just the controls within the section and then if valid, display the next section.

The code for validating controls within a section might look like (I'm assuming that subsequent groups of controls are hidden and that the next section is only visible if the current section is valid)

```
$('button').click(function () {
  var container = $(this).closest('fieldset'); // assumes groups of controlls and the button are wrapped in <fieldset> tag
  var isValid = true;  
  $.each(container.find('input'), function () { // could add select, textarea if applicable
    $('form').validate().element($(this));
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
      isValid = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (isValid) {
    container.next('fieldset').show().find('input').first().focus(); // set focus to first input of next fieldset
    container.hide(); // hide the previous container?
  } else {
    // display an error message?
    container.find('.error').text('please complete this section'); // assumes an element with class="error" to display message
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes i am not intresting into submit my first 4 forms that's why i just check their validation if valid show next form.
I want to know how to merge the value of first 4 forms with last form. Is it possible ?

Comment: No, but whats wrong with doing as I suggested. You can just validate just the previous controls before moving on to the next.

Comment: Yes, but for that i need to check every field before moving to next form. It is dummy example i have 90 fields within the Model.

Comment: No you don't, you only need to validate the controls within the section that the button is in. I'll update my answer shortly to show how (and if you have that many controls you certainly don't want to be copying each control to a hidden inputs in the last form).

Comment: Right Dear let me check both solutions. Thanks for your answer